# Installing Neo4j as a Windows service

Tags: neo4j

I have been a Neo4j community edition user for a couple of years now from the v1.x releases. In the early times there was no Windows Installer and so it was always run as a console or as a Windows service. In one release in the 2.0.x series **Neo4jInstaller.bat** was introduced to make it easier to install as a service. However, the documentation for the 2.2.x series no longer includes a reference to installing as a Windows service. See [the Neo4j manual v2.2.3](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.3/server-installation.html#windows-install). If you look at the 2.1.x or 2.0.x documents the section on installing as a windows service is still present. This has led me to the conclusion it may have been deprecated as an advised deployment approach for Neo4j v2.2.x. Does anyone know if this is the case and why? If so what is the recommended deployment technique on a Windows server?

I should point out that running the install command as usual still works.

```
bin\Neo4jInstaller.nat install
```

Answer (score 2):

I think Neo technology deprecated that, because they have to maintain it. Also they doesn't support for Linux Service anymore.

You can create Windows service by yourself. It's not hard. Following link should help you.

[How to create a Windows service by using Sc.exe](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/251192)
[NSSM - the Non-Sucking Service Manager](http://nssm.cc/)